# Remove element if specific class exist inside element

Tags: jquery, class, element

Current code.

```
 ------

        <div class="wrapper">
             <div class="page-1"></div>
             <div class="page-2"></div>
             <div class="page-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
             <div class="page-4"></div>
             <div class="page-5"></div>
             <div class="page-6"></div>
        </div>

------
```

//Jquery finds page-4 and removes whole wrapper element.

```
------
    <div class="wrapper">
         <div class="page-1"></div>
         <div class="page-2"></div>
         <div class="page-3"></div>
    </div>

------
```

I simply want that page-4, and its wrapper not the other wrappers.

Havn't figured it out yet how to exact fix this prob.
Im open to any suggestions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
$('.page-4').closest('.wrapper').detach(); or .remove()
```

Here is the working fiddle
    http://jsfiddle.net/yUsqC/2/
This will remove only the parent wrapper not other wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$('#page-4').parent().remove();
```

You say "class" in your question title, but based on the text of your question you appear to only care about an element with a specific ID.  Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Yeah I was meaning class, I misstyped :p. gues its the same thing

Comment: Class and ID are very different.  Make sure you know the difference!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#page-4').parent().remove();
```

Or did you want to unwrap it and leave the contents behind?

```
$('#page-4').unwrap();
```